# Installing Ubuntu 10.10 on Sony VAIO VPCF133FX/H 16.4 inches. Will it work?

Tags: drivers, sony-vaio, ubuntu-10.10

The exact spec of my model can be found here:

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6700956&CatId=4938

I am trying to install the 64-bit version, non-server: http://ubuntu.media.mit.edu/ubuntu-releases/10.10/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso

When it booted up, it did not recognize the trackpad, which is pretty bad. It also did not recognize certain keys on the keyboard. Now, the indicator with drivers available did come up, but I did not get a chance to click on it. With a USB mouse plugged in (and possibly a USB keyboard), I should have better luck. But, it still is kind of sketchy that drivers did not load up by default.

So, should I try installing 10.10 on my VAIO now, or should I wait? Sony is known for using funky hardware that causes Linux users pain, but I thought that in 2010 this is a non-issue. I think my laptop first came out in August.

If you have tried / succeeded at installing any common flavor Linux on this model, I would love to hear from you. If you have not, but think can contribute a good advise, then please do.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the live version? Test it out first with a live boot.

Comment: Did the laptop have internet access during the installation? perhaps Ubuntu would fetch drivers online.

Comment: Live was the only option, I think. Perhaps this is how the installs will happen from now on. Internet access - I will check it once I try a USB mouse. However, which command(s) should I use?